# NSComparisonResult is not showing proper result

Tags: comparison

I need to compair current time  with two time rang, its work fine in every case but when I check "12:00 PM" to "01:30 PM", it give me wrong value.

```
NSComparisonResult timeStart=[@"01:02 PM"  compare:@"12:00 PM"];
NSComparisonResult timeEnd=[@"01:02 PM" compare:@"01:30 PM"];
```

both `timeStart` and `timeEnd` are -1?

where `timeStart` is bigger so it should be 1 which is not.

Please help......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two strings, not two times. You need to first construct `NSDate` objects with say `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFromString:` method, then do your comparison.